# Programming a tic tac toe game in JAVA. Using many if statements how would i get the game to read a tie game?

Tags: java, if-statement, tic-tac-toe

**PROMPT**

Welcome to play the game of guessing who is winning!
Please enter your game 1 board (* to exit) > XXOOOXXOO
Your game 1 is as follows:
XXO
OOX
XOO
Your game 1: Tie

Please enter your game 2 board (* to exit) > XXXOOXXOO
Your game 2 is as follows:
XXX
OOX
XOO
Your game 2: X won the game by row 1.
etc.

---

### How could I make it read a tie game?

```
package PA6;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PA6 {
private static char [ ] [ ] ttt = new char [4] [4] ;
private static int gameNum = 1;


public static void main(String[] args)
{//MAIN OPEN
System.out.println("Welcome to play the game of guessing who is winning!");
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
String gameString;
System.out.println("Please enter your game " + gameNum + " board (* to exit) > ");
gameString = scan.nextLine();
int n; 

while (!gameString.equals("*"))
    {//WHILE LOOP OPEN
    System.out.println("Your game " + gameNum + " is as follows: ");
        n = 0;
    ttt = new char [4][4];
    for(int i = 1 ; i < 4; i++)
        {//FOR LOOP OPEN
            for(int j = 1; j < 4; j++)
            {//NESTED FOR LOOP OPEN 
                ttt [i][j]= gameString.charAt(n);
                    n++;
            }//NESTED FOR LOOP CLOSED
        }//FOR LOOP CLOSED
    System.out.println(ttt[1][1] + "" + ttt[1][2] + "" + ttt[1][3]);
    System.out.println(ttt[2][1] + "" + ttt[2][2] + "" + ttt[2][3]);
    System.out.println(ttt[3][1] + "" + ttt[3][2] + "" + ttt[3][3]);

    if(winRow1('O' , ttt))
        System.out.println("Your game " + gameNum + ": O won the game by row 1");
    if(winRow2('O' , ttt))
        System.out.println("Your game " + gameNum + ": O won the game by row 2");
    if(winRow3('O' , ttt))
        System.out.println("Your game " + gameNum + ": O won the game by row 3");
    if(winRow1('X' , ttt))
        System.out.println("Your game " + gameNum + ": X won the game by row 1");
    if(winRow2('X' , ttt))
        System.out.println("Your game " + gameNum + ": X won the game by row 2");
    if(winRow3('X' , ttt))
        System.out.println("Your game " + gameNum + ": X won the game by row 3");
    if(winColumn1('O' , ttt))
        System.out.println("Your game " + gameNum + ": O won the game by Column 1");
    if(winColumn2('O' , ttt))
        System.out.println("Your game " + gameNum + ": O won the game by Column 2");
    if(winColumn3('O' , ttt))
        System.out.println("Your game " + gameNum + ": O won the game by Column 3");
    if(winColumn1('X' , ttt))
        System.out.println("Your game " + gameNum + ": X won the game by Column 1");
    if(winColumn2('X' , ttt))
        System.out.println("Your game " + gameNum + ": X won the game by Column 2");
    if(winColumn3('X' , ttt))
        System.out.println("Your game " + gameNum + ": X won the game by Column 3");
    if(winDiagonal1('O' , ttt))
        System.out.println("Your game " + gameNum + ": O won the game by diagonal 1");
    if(winDiagonal1('X' , ttt))
        System.out.println("Your game " + gameNum + ": X won the game by diagonal 1");
    if(winDiagonal2('O' , ttt))
        System.out.println("Your game " + gameNum + ": O won the game by diagonal 2");
    if(winDiagonal2('X' , ttt))
        System.out.println("Your game " + gameNum + ": X won the game by diagonal 2");

    gameNum++;

    System.out.print("Please enter your game " + gameNum + " board (* to exit) > ");
    gameString = scan.nextLine();




    }//WHILE LOOP CLOSED
}//MAIN CLOSED

public static boolean winDiagonal1( char player, char a [][]) 
   { 
if ( ttt[1][1] == player && ttt[2][2] == player && ttt[3][3] == player )
    return true;   
return false; 
   }

public static boolean winDiagonal2 (char player, char a [][])
   {
    if( ttt[1][3] == player && ttt[2][2] == player && ttt[3][1] == player )
        return true;
    return false;
   }
public static boolean winRow1 (char player, char a [][])
   {
if (ttt[1][1] == player && ttt[1][2] == player && ttt[1][3] == player)
    return true;
return false;
   }

public static boolean winRow2 (char player, char a [][])
   {
if (ttt[2][1] == player && ttt[2][2] == player && ttt[2][3] == player)
    return true;
return false;
   }

public static boolean winRow3 (char player, char a [][])
   {    
if (ttt[3][1] == player && ttt[3][2] == player && ttt[3][3] == player)
    return true;
return false;
   }
public static boolean winColumn1 (char player, char a [][])
   {    
if (ttt[1][1] == player && ttt[2][1] == player && ttt [3][1] == player)
    return true;
return false;
   }

public static boolean winColumn2 (char player, char a [][])
   { 
if (ttt[1][2] == player && ttt[2][2] == player && ttt [3][2] == player)
    return true;
return false;
   }

public static boolean winColumn3 (char player, char a [][])
   {
if (ttt[1][3] == player && ttt[2][3] == player && ttt [3][3] == player)
    return true;
return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: If you have conditions for victory and loss, then a tie is neither of those.

Comment: @Makoto How would i go about doing that. An else statement?

Comment: Don't think you need it.  Despite that it's not written in an exactly clean way, think of it like this:  what happens if neither X or O have won in any direction (horizontal, vertical, or diagonal)? It'd be another statement you print out after you check and assert all of those cases.

Comment: @Makoto I think I understand what you are saying. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you convert your if statements to combined if else if statements than what is left in your else case will be the tie.

```
if(winRow1('O' , ttt))
        System.out.println("Your game " + gameNum + ": O won the game by row 1");
else if(winRow2('O' , ttt))
        System.out.println("Your game " + gameNum + ": O won the game by row 2");
.
.
.
else
        System.out.println("Your game " + gameNum + ": It is a tie");
```

By the way,this way you could avoid multiple messages like when there are one row and one column fulticked at the same time ;).